# Should data entry restrictions (Constraints) work when entering data into an QGIS attribute table directly?

Tags: qgis, attribute-table

When editing field values directly from the attribute table, **Constraints** don't work as expected (but they do when creating a new feature).

Is this normal behavior or is it a bug?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Constraints does not work at all in attribute tables!

See the developer's discussion here:
https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/issues/29721